# Getting CalloutException when testing Batchable class with Callouts and HttpCalloutMock

Tags: unit-test, batch, callout, httpcalloutmock

I'm trying to write test code for a `Batchable` class that `AllowsCallouts`.  I've written a lot of other test code that uses `HttpCalloutMock` classes, and planned to do so for this class as well.

And, per best practices, I'm setting up my test data before calling `Test.startTest()`.  Even so, I get a CalloutException:

> System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

This somewhat makes sense, because my `start()` method passes a SOQL query to `Database.getQueryLocator()` and my `execute()` method makes the web callouts.  I'm guessing that when my test method calls `test.stopTest()`, both `start()` and `execute()` run in the same context.  In regular batch operation, they happen in separate contexts so there isn't any uncommitted work.

I intend to work around this by calling the methods directly, possibly even calling `start()` before `Test.startTest()`, and then using the returned `Database.QueryLocator` to get the list of records I'll pass into `execute()`.

I don't like the fact that I'm not testing the batch size used by the static method that kicks off the batch with `Database.executeBatch()`, so I'll probably have that use a constant that I can reference from my test code to ensure it's using the same batch size.

Salesforce kind of addresses this in the "Asynchronous Apex and Mock Callouts" section of the [Summer '13 Release Notes](https://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf), but they don't make reference to Batchable classes with Callouts.  They only talk about making callouts and testing Batchable classes in the same test method.

**So, my question is whether there is a better way to write this test.**  I'm also throwing this out so others searching the site can learn about possible workarounds.

Comment: So there is no DML in your execute before the callouts ?

Comment: Correct.  The Batch runs fine outside of the tests.

Comment: You can see my comments on a previous post here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12820/testing-a-combination-of-webservice-callouts-and-inserts/12849#12849
But basically, I think you are stuck testing the callout part separately from the batch execution...hopefully, next release will fix this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is a 'hack' but you may be able to call your batchable class methods inside your testmethod without running in a `Database.executeBatch(...);` method call. I have done this for a customer who needed higher test coverage; their batch apex was simple and didn't require the batchable context to be set.

TestCode:-

```
    MyBatchableClass mbc = new MyBatchableClass();

        List<MySObject__c> scope = {list of previously inserted objects};
        mbc.execute(null, scope);
        Test.startTest();
        WebServiceMockImpl mock = new WebServiceMockImpl();

        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, mock);
        //Webservice call out in here
        mbc.finish(null);

        Test.stopTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

Richard has the right idea (so I selected his answer as correct), and I just wanted to include my final solution for others to reference.

```
    // In API 27, we have been unable to test Batchable classes that make
    // callouts, so we emulate the testing instead.  Call the start() method
    // to get the QueryLocator, then iterate to get the records, and then
    // call Test.startTest() and manually submit them to the execute() method.
    // Note that this technique wouldn't work if any of the methods needed to
    // actually reference the Database.BatchableContext object (which we pass
    // as null).

    Database.BatchableContext bc;
    MyBatchableClass mbc = new MyBatchableClass ();
    Database.QueryLocatorIterator iter = mbc.start( bc).iterator();
    List<My_Custom_Object__c> batch = new List<My_Custom_Object__c>();
    Integer batchsize = MyBatchableClass.BATCH_SIZE;
    while (batchsize-- > 0 && iter.hasNext())
    {
        batch.add( (My_Custom_Object__c) iter.next());
    }

    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock( HttpCalloutMock.class, new MyCalloutMock());
    mhc.execute( bc, batch);
    mhc.finish( bc);
    Test.stopTest();

    // asserts go here
```