# Why Batch can't work in unit-test?

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, httpcalloutmock

There are 2 methods will callout and insert.I wrote 2 batches to invoke my method. I use the one invoke the other one to avoid System.CalloutException,and it's useful when i run them.

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        Database.executeBatch(new TrelloChangeTaskBatch());
}
```

But when i create MockHttpCallout class and use Test.startTest() and stopTest() in my test class to run the batches.

```
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockTrelloHttpResponseGenerator());
        Database.executeBatch(new TrelloBatch());
        Test.stopTest();
```

it's still happened.

> System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please
>   commit or rollback before calling out in test class

I tried to delete startTest() and stopTest() but  it's invalid.More than that i can't use @feature.
Somebody told my isRunningTest() maybe useful, but i don't know how to use it in my case because there are no example in document.

Anybody know how to solve this problem in unit test? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug in the mock implementation and a search would have return several results.

This one being the most relevant: [Getting CalloutException when testing Batchable class with Callouts and HttpCalloutMock](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-calloutexception-when-testing-batchable-class-with-callouts-and-httpcall)

Regardless, in order to cover your batch class, instantiate the batch class and call the start, execute, and finish methods directly:

```
global class Batch_Create_Client_Accounts implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {


    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {


    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }



}
```

Test:

```
Batch_Create_Client_Accounts b = New Batch_Create_Client_Accounts();
b.start(null);
b.execute(null,YOUR LIST OF RECORDS);
b.finish;
```

OR

```
Batch_Create_Client_Accounts b = New Batch_Create_Client_Accounts();

b.execute(null,b.start(null).getQuery());
b.finish;
```