# Getting error in test class System callout exception

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api

I am consuming webservice rest api(post method) in apex class using webservice static method.i wrote test class but i am getting System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out.

Here is mycode:

```
Global with sharing class WebServiceClassGetQLIT 
{
WebService static String InsertQuoLiItems(String QuoteNumber,String quoteID)
    {
String jsonpostdata = '{"quoteNo":"'+quoteObj.Erapid_Quote_no__c+'","environment": "'+environment+'","userId":"'+userId+'"}';
                system.debug('jsonpostdata'+jsonpostdata);
                string endpointUrl=Label.SFXT_Server_IP+'/rep_web/api/quote/lineItems';
                Http http=new Http();
                HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
                req.setEndpoint(endpointUrl);
                req.setMethod('POST');
                req.setTimeOut(120000);
                req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                req.setBody(jsonpostdata );

                HttpResponse res;
                res=new http().send(req);
                system.debug('response'+res.getBody());
                String jsonparse = res.getBody();
                QuoteLineItemResponse lineItemResponse = (QuoteLineItemResponse)JSON.deserialize(jsonparse, QuoteLineItemResponse.class);
                system.debug('lineitem response'+lineItemResponse);
                Quote_line_Items__c QuoLObj;
                list<Quote_line_Items__c> QuoLOList = new list<Quote_line_Items__c>();
//mapping feilds
}
}
```

test class is:

```
@isTest
private class WebServiceClassGetQLIT_UnitTest 
{
static testmethod void testAccountCallout() {
         RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        SingleRequestMock fakeResponse = new SingleRequestMock(200,'OK','[{"quoteNo":"102153_00","environment": "US_SANDBOX","userId":"gennesse"}]',null);
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, fakeResponse);

        Account acc = new Account(name = 'Testing Account',Country__c = 'India',type = 'C/S Company');
        insert acc;
        Contact con = new Contact(LastName = 'testing',accountId=acc.Id);
        insert con;
        Project__c proj = new Project__c(Country__c = 'Afghanistan',Name = 'Test Project',Project_Type__c = 'New Construction',Lead_Source__c = 'Advertisement',
            Project_Source__c = 'sac',Project_Stage__c = 'Completed',Postal_Code_Zip_Code__c = '6514',Funding_Type__c = 'Private');
        insert proj;
        C_S_Opportunity__c opp = new C_S_Opportunity__c(Project__c = proj.id,Stage__c = 'Prospecting',CS_Product_Added__c = 'ADS',Project_type_text__c = 'Trade(C/S)',       
                                        Close_Date__c = system.today());
        insert opp;     
        Product2 p = new Product2(name='unittest',Family = 'License');
        insert p;
        //Pricebook2 stdPb = [select Id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true limit 1];
        string stdPb = '01s30000000J5mMAAS';   //01s30000000J5mMAAS    
                 //pbe.pricebook2id = stdPb.id;
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(pricebook2id = stdPb,product2id = p.id,unitprice=1.0,isActive = true);
        insert pbe;

        Quotes__c Quo=new Quotes__c();

        Quo.Erapid_Quote_no__c = '015403_00';
        Quo.Account__c = Acc.Id;
        Quo.C_S_Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
        Quo.Contact__c = Con.Id;
        Quo.Status__c = 'Draft';
        Quo.Description__c = 'ae';
        Quo.Contact_customer__c = con.id;
        Quo.Quote_Type__c = 'New';
        Quo.Quote_Origin__c = 'ALTERNATE';
        Quo.First_Date_of_Forecasted__c = date.newInstance(2008, 12, 1);
        Quo.Expiration_Date__c = date.newInstance(2008, 12, 1);
        Quo.Grand_Total__c = 12;
        Quo.Discount__c = 12;
        Quo.Project__c = proj.Id;
        Insert Quo;
        test.startTest();
        string r = WebServiceClassGetQLIT.InsertQuoLiItems('102153_00' , quo.ID);
        test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Comment: IN addition your test is not actually testing anything. All it is doing is running code. You need to check for outcomes both for expected and unexpected.

Answer (score 4):

See this: [You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003701)

> A Web Service Callout may not occur after a DML statement within the
>   same transaction. To achieve the required action, the transaction must
>   be separated into two parts so that the DML transaction is completed
>   before the Web Service Callout occurs.

and this is the reason of your issue:

> The Test.startTest statement must appear before the Test.setMock
>   statement.

Ref::[System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17293/system-calloutexception-you-have-uncommitted-work-pending-please-commit-or-rol)