# Schedulable calling a batchable: doable? testable?

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex

I have a process that needs to run once daily.  It will first need to make a series of callouts to get information (sms email address) to update contacts, and it will then need to send emails using the updated contacts.  The callouts may exceed 10, so I have designed a Batchable class that can find all the correct records, make the callouts in batches, and update the records.  From the `finish()` method I want to invoke the method to send the emails.

Here's the rough outline:

```
global class Reminders_Schedulable implements Schedulable {

    global void execute() {
        // OMITTED: do a little setup work 

        // Run the batchable to make callouts and update contact's SMS email addresses
        Database.executeBatch(new SMSGatewayUtil_Batchable(), SMSGatewayUtil.MAX_BATCH_SIZE);
    }

    global static void SendReminders() {
        // send the actual reminders using the updated contacts
    }
}

global class SMSGatewayUtil_Batchable 
             implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
         system.debug('&&&& SMSGatewayUtil_Batchable.start');
         return Database.getQueryLocator(...);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, list<Contact> contacts) {
         system.debug('&&&& SMSGatewayUtil_Batchable.execute');
         SMSGatewayUtil.UpdateContactsSMSEmail(contacts);
         update contacts;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
         system.debug('&&&& SMSGatewayUtil_Batchable.finish');
         Reminders_Schedulable.SendReminders();
    }

}
```

So the scheduleable class's `execute()` method runs the batchable, which updates makes callouts and updates contacts; finally the batchable's `finish()` method calls a static method
to send the emails, using the updated contacts.  Is there are reason why the schedulable's `execute()` method shouldn't be able to call the `batchable()`?  I don't think there is, but thought I'd check.

The bigger question - is this testable as is?  I have a test method that calls `system.schedule` to run the schedulable (in between `startTest` and `stopTest`).  The execute() method is called, and I see the SMSGatewayUtil_Batchable constructor invocation on the `executeBatch()` line in the log, but the batchable doesn't appear to run - the debug statements in the batchable class do not even appear in the log.  There's also no error messages.

**Update:** As I failed to mention originally, my test class is setting up a mock interface for the callout.  The question that I have is that the Database.Batchable is being constructed but not invoked - as shown in my outline above, each method in the Batchable has a debug statement, and none of them are showing up in the debug log - not even the start() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can call batchable classes from schedulable classes.  This is a very common use case.

As for testing you'll want to test them separately.  Test methods for my schedulable classes that invoke a batchable class just verify that the batchable class is queued after the scheduled class has executed.  I then have a separate test methods for my batch class that is queued for the test directly rather than through the schedulable class.

The reason behind this is the Test.stopTest() method only clears out queues (future, batch, scheduled) once.  So you can have multiple future and batch calls run at that point, but if those cause any further queuing of processes they aren't run.  Currently there isn't a way to flush the queues twice, just need to test them separately, which personnally I feel is a better and clearer testing scheme since it separates the various roles of each class better.

Comment: "Test.stopTest() method only clears out queues (future, batch, scheduled) once" - aha, this makes sense.  I just replaced my test method's System.schedule call with a direct call to the class's execute() method, and everything works.  Which is fine... I don't need to test the scheduler, just my execute method.

Comment: That statement is not true. The code I posted proves otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the normal design of a scheduled class is to kick off a batch process. It's also possible to combine the scheduler and batch into a single class, using the following design:

```
public class MyProcessor implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select id from account]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, Account[] records) {
        System.debug('*** Do Something Here ***');
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        System.debug('*** Do Something Here ***');
    }
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
}
```

Note that execute won't fire if there is nothing to do. Here's an example test.

```
@isTest
class MyProcessorTest implements HttpCalloutMock {
    public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setStatusCode(401);  // We demo "unauthorized" here
        return res;
    }
    @isTest
    static void test() {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MyProcessorTest());
        MyProcessor mp = new MyProcessor();
        Account a = new Account(Name='Test');
        insert a;
        System.schedule('Test', '0 0 * ? * * *', mp);
        Test.startTest();
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

*Edit*: Also, I should mention that callouts need to use the [mock callout interface](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm), because you can't actually perform a callout during a test (a protection against updating a live system with dummy data). I've updated the test to reflect how you can use this interface.

*Edit 2*: So, batch callouts are not supported in testing, but calling a batch from a scheduled call is. Thus, it prompted me to write the following code (with 100% coverage):

```
public class MyProcessor implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    @TestVisible execute mode;

    public MyProcessor() {
        Map<Boolean, Type> modes = new Map<Boolean, Type>();
        modes.put(test.isRunningTest(), testmode.class);
        modes.put(!test.isrunningtest(), livemode.class);
        mode = (execute)modes.get(true).newinstance();
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select id from account]);
    }

    public interface execute {
        void execute(Account[] records);
    }

    public class testMode implements execute {
        public void execute(Account[] records) {
        }
    }
    public class liveMode implements execute {
        public void execute(Account[] records) {
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setMethod('GET');
            req.setEndpoint('https://www.google.com/');
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        }
    }            
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, Account[] records) {
        mode.execute(records);
        System.debug('*** Do Something Here ***');
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        System.debug('*** Do Something Here ***');
    }
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Database.executeBatch(new MyProcessor());
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class MyProcessorTest implements HttpCalloutMock {
    public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        res.setStatus('Found');
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.setBody('Hello World!');
        return res;
    }
    @isTest static void test1() {
        MyProcessor mp = new MyProcessor(); 
        Account record = new Account(Name='Test');
        insert record;
        Test.startTest();
        System.schedule('Test', '0 0 * ? * * *', mp);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
    @isTest static void test2() {
        MyProcessor mp = new MyProcessor();
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MyProcessorTest());
        mp.mode = new MyProcessor.livemode();
        mp.mode.execute([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);
        Test.stoptest();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Note that execute won't fire if there is nothing to do" - it's true that the Batchable interface's execute won't fire if start doesn't return any records.  However, my start method immediately writes a debug message, and that message is not appearing in the log.  As noted in the question, I see the Batchable constructor being invoked (in the ExecuteBatch statement), but no debug messages from inside the batchable appear.  I suspect that the testing framework doesn't support a call to Batchable.execute inside a Schedulable.execute implementation, but I haven't found confirmation in the docs.

Comment: And yes, my test method calls SetMock, but the code that makes the callout is inside the Batchable, and is never invoked.

Comment: Accepted @Ralph's answer as it had the testing info I needed, but +1 here for good sample code and explanation.

Comment: @JasonClark Interesting, but this example code runs in my organization-- and achieves 100% coverage. Perhaps there's something else going on? More to the point, I don't think that answer is correct, since I am able to get 100% coverage with my example code.

Comment: The problem appears to be related to the callout itself. Are you sure you're not getting an error? I keep getting the "uncommitted work pending" error while trying to test this; commenting that out achieves perfect coverage.

Comment: Also... check your logging level. Debug statements may not always be output. Try an assert(false) and see if your test still passes.

Comment: Hmm, that's news to me.  Are you seeing your debug statements in the output?  Not sure if calling the schedulable class before Test.startTest() leads to any differences in behavior.

Comment: Definitely sure. I get 100% coverage if I don't try to callout.

Comment: @Ralph When you get a moment, I'd like to have a chat with you about this. I'm trying to understand why I can't callout correctly in the test method.

Comment: [This answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12820/testing-a-combination-of-webservice-callouts-and-inserts/12849#12849) suggests that I've run face-first into a bug regarding callouts in batch apex code. That's unfortunate.

Comment: That's my post, and it is still, as far as I know, an issue. I usually end up moving the code out of the batch, and into its own class which I then test directly using a mock interface, and preventing the execution of that code in the batch in a test via an isrunningtest() check - messy, but unavoidable.

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC That was my conclusion, too. I created some new code that illustrates that factor. Such a burden.

Comment: Do you think that is a bug? I have always considered it a limitation that will hopefully get fixed, so never raised it as a bug - but should I?

Comment: It isn't documented as a limitation, and the code should work according to the way the documentation is written, and so therefore it is a bug. The issue appears to be that CronTrigger never commits and causes the error in question.